# Using gl_FragCoord to create a hole in a quad

Tags: glsl, webgl

I am learning WebGL, and would like to do the following:

Create a 3D quad with a square hole in it using a fragment shader.

It looks like I need to set `gl_FragColor` based on `gl_FragCoord` appropriately.

So should I:

a) Convert `gl_FragCoord` from window coordinates to model coordinates, do the appropriate geometry check, and set color.

OR

b) Somehow pass the hole information from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. Maybe use a texture coordinate. I am not clear on this part.

I am fuzzy about implementing either of the above, so I'd appreaciate some coding hints on  either.

My background is that of an OpenGL old timer who has not kept up with the new shading language paradigm, and is now trying to catch up...

Edit (27/03/2011):

I have been able to successfully implement the above based on the tex coord hint. I've written up this example at the link below:

[Quads with holes - example](http://tat-tvam-asi.in/programming/webgl/quads-with-holes/)

[image: Quads with holes - example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be with texture coords. Simply supply the corrds as an extra attribute array then pass through to the fragment shader using a varying. The shaders should contain something like:

vertex:

```
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(){
     vTexCoord=aTexCoord;
     .......
}
```

fragment:

```
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main(){
     if(vTexCoord.x>{lower x limit} && vTexCoord.x<{upper x limit} && vTexCoord.y>{lower y limit} && vTexCoord.y<{upper y limit}){
discard; //this tell GFX to discard this fragment entirly
}
.....
}
```

Comment: A little confused above the above - so is there a real texture involved with some sort of alpha channel, or are we simply using texture coordinates that will be interpolated by the fragment shader, but no actual texture set up? Thanks.

Comment: Got it - I understand what you said now. No texture set up is necessary, just a vertex array with the texture coords. Works great, thanks!

Comment: How are you supplying the buffers? GLSL isn't enough.